# Inconsistent behavior from release and debug versions of code

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am having some bizarre behavior here. 
In my app, I use a gesture recognizer to present the user with a dialog of options (using `DisplayActionSheet`).

When I run the code in debug mode, I get the expected result every time. However when I run the app using release code, I get nothing.. The popup is not being called and as best I can tell the code is never even executing...

Implementation in .CS

```
/// <summary>
/// Handle the tapped event for the carousel image
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
public async void OnTapped(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            string action = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet(StringTools.GetStringResource("szPhotoOptions"),
                                      null,
                                      StringTools.GetStringResource("szOK"),
                                      StringTools.GetStringResource("szKeyPhoto"),
                                      StringTools.GetStringResource("szEditPhoto"),
                                      StringTools.GetStringResource("szSavePhoto"),
                                      StringTools.GetStringResource("szSharePhoto"),
                                      StringTools.GetStringResource("szEmailPhoto"),
                                      StringTools.GetStringResource("szDeletePhoto")).ConfigureAwait(true);

            await TapHandler.ImageTapHandler((Photos)((TappedEventArgs)e).Parameter, action, KeyImage).ConfigureAwait(true);
            PulltoRefresh_Refreshing(null, null);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"AddWeaon.xaml.cs->OnTapped()->{ex.Message}==={ex.InnerException}==={ex.StackTrace}");
    }
}
```

Declaration for the handler (declared in the xaml)

```
            <DataTemplate x:Key="CarouselitemTemplate">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}" Tapped="OnTapped" />
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Image
                        Aspect="AspectFit"
                        HeightRequest="350"
                        Source="{Binding Path=Image, Converter={StaticResource FillImageFromBytes}}"
                        WidthRequest="250" />
                    <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>

        .........


        <!-- implementation for the carousel, and images -->
                    <Label Text="Images" />
                    <syncfusion:SfCarousel
                        x:Name="carousel"
                        HeightRequest="350"
                        ItemHeight="480"
                        ItemSpacing="2"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Key=CarouselitemTemplate}"
                        ItemWidth="250"
                        ViewMode="Default"
                        WidthRequest="400"
                        Offset="1" />
```

Finally here is the code for the tap handler class.

```
    static class TapHandler
    {
        private static readonly SemaphoreSlim Semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

        public static async Task ImageTapHandler(Photos IncomingImage, string action, ImageButton KeyImage)
        {
            await Semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
            try
            {
                //Something went wrong, and there is no action to take
                if (IncomingImage == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(action))
                    return;

                PhotosRepository PhotoRepo = new PhotosRepository();

                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Action: {0} On {1}", action, IncomingImage.Path));

                //Display share dialog
                if (action.Contains("Share"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!File.Exists(IncomingImage.Path))
                        {
                            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(IncomingImage.Image);
                            DependencyService.Get<ISave>().Save(true, IncomingImage.Path, "image/jpeg", stream);
                        }
                        ShareFileRequest sf = new ShareFileRequest($"Sharing {IncomingImage.FileName}", new ShareFile(IncomingImage.Path, "image/jpeg"));

                        await Share.RequestAsync(sf).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"ImageTapHandler.cs->Share()--{ex.Message}==={ex.InnerException}--===--{ex.StackTrace}");
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        /*
                        if (File.Exists(szPath))
                            File.Delete(szPath);
                            */
                    }
                }
    .......
```

When run, the `DisplayActionSheet` gives the user the options to choose from for the image. I would like to change this eventually to use a `sfCircularMenu` object, but for version 1.0 of the app the `DisplayActionSheet` works well enough...

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: How do you use sfCircularMenu? What is the difference between the sfCircularMenu and DisplayActionSheet  on version1?

Comment: I don't use it at this time. I was considering transitioning to using it, but since the issue seems to be cutting me off before it even gets to that point in the code, I need to figure out how to make DisplayActionSheet work first. I've tried adding code to signal when it enters the function, and it appears that the OnTapped function is not even getting called.

Comment: In the end sfCircularMenu is just a cleaner more graphic menu that can be called than using the DisplayActionSheet.

Comment: Okay, I found that it has to do with the code shrinker, using the d8 shrinker I get this behavior, but if I use ProGuard, I get the expected behavior. So I am perplexed as to what is causing it. In the end, I have my release code working again so I guess I am happy.. Ish...